# If $f$ is analytic in and on simple loop $C$, then if $z_0$ lies inside $C$ then $f(z_0)$ lies inside the image $f(C)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I start on this?

I'm thinking about somehow using the maximum and minimum modulus principle so I can guarantee that $f(z_0)$ lies in a annulus-sector region, given by $z_1<|z|<z_2$ and $\theta_1 < \arg(z)<\theta_2$, where they are the minimum and maximum arguments and moduli of $f(z)$. I think that I am allowed to estimate the location of $f(z_0)$ in this way because $\log(f(z))=\text{Log}(|f(z)||+i\arg(f(z))$, and both are harmonic functions.

I've tested it out on desmos, and I have experimentally supported that the property referenced in the question title is true, but I can't seem to prove it. It works for all simple closed contours $C$, which satisfies my needs, but I can't seem to prove it. I know that I'm especially missing something because it holds for even simple concave contours.

Comment: Just to be sure, “inside” means “is an element of the interior”?

Comment: analytic functions are open mappings, so yea...

Comment: @Clayton yes. i was explaining my problem in visual terms

Comment: @mathworker21 i sort of understand the open mapping property and i figured it had something to do with this, but I can't seem to figure out how to prove this exactl

Comment: let's say we have some contour that encloses one zero of $f(z)$. then let $\sigma$ be the smallest modulus of $f(z)$ on the contour. by rouche's theorem, $f(z)-\sigma$ also has a zero within the contour, and so $f(z)$ takes on all values $|z|<\sigma$ within $C_r$. how can i utilize that property?

Comment: How do you define the inside of $f(C)$ if $f$ is not univalent and $f(C)$ has self intersections? There are simple examples where $f$ maps inside points to $f(C)$, like say $z^2-z$ on the unit disc where $f(0)=f(1)$

Comment: @Conrad this was actually part of a probelm that asked: if f is one-to-one on a simple contour and analytic on and within the contour, then prove that f is one-to-one within the contour as well

Comment: Argument principle

Comment: The one-to-one hypothesis is crucial since then $f(C)$ is a simple closed curve and for any $a$ inside it, $f-a$ has index (or topological degree) 1 w.r. to it, and for any $a$ outside, index $0$. That is true if $f$ just continuous but analyticity implies zeros are isolated and have positive degree, so degree 1 means one zero, so it means one to one inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $z_0$ is not an omitted value of $f$.
Example : consider $f(z) = e^z$ on |z|<1. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z|<1$. 
Take $z_0= 0$. Then $f(z) \neq z_0$ for all $z\in |z|<1$.
If $z_0$ is not omitted value of $f$,  then by open mapping theorem, the result follows